# kp and Mp in German engineering text from 1963

Tags: abbreviation, technical-terminology

I have a German engineering thesis written in 1963 from Technische Hochschule Hannover.

In the results the author displays stress with the units of kp/cm² and the load as Mp. I am assuming the “p” is for *Pfund* which I am finding equal to 500 grams.

However, when I convert this to modern units of MPa and Newtons the results are too large to make sense. The results are about twenty times higher than what I expect:

> 1 kp/cm² ≙ (1 kp/cm²) · (500 g/p) · (9.81 N/kg) · (100 cm/m)² = 49,050,000 N/m² = 49.05 MPa
>
> 1 Mp ≙ (1 Mp) · (500 g/p) · (9.81 N/kg) = 4,905 kN

Could kp and Mp mean something else than *Kilopfund* and *Megapfund?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about an aspect of German language. This is a question about units in technic and physics.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Hmm, but there are language-specific differences; e.g., in French it was called _kilogramme-poids_ (or _kilogramme-force_) and abbreviated in a different way. If the question were to be closed, though, I’d think “general reference” would be a better reason ([WP de](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/KP), [WP en](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KP), even [WP fr](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/KP)). Anyway, voted to leave open.

Comment: Pfund would be abbreviated to *Pfd.* or as WIkipedia states (but I don't remember ever having seen it) to *Pf*, in both cases with a capital P.

Comment: Pfund ist generell in der Wissenschaft nicht verwendet worden, nur an Lebensmitteltheken, zumindest nicht seit Einführung metrischer Maße vor mehr als 100 Jahren.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's a now deprecated unit:

[Kilopond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram-force), (abbreviated "kp", the English term: kilogramm-force), that measured the force via gravitational acceleration of an object with a mass of one kg in standard gravity.

Expressed in modern SI units it is equal to 9.80665 N.

*Mp* is Megapond, 1000 *kp*

Comment: As the [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilopond) says, In Germany the _Kilopond_ has been replaced by the Newton in 1978. I passed my Abitur in 1980, and can remember the _kp_ being used in schoolbooks, probably until 1977, or maybe one or two years before.